# How do I change the UIStatusBar color to .lightContent in the MoreTabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistatusbar

I have a `UITabBarController` with more than 5 `UIViewControllers`. I have set the value in my `info.plist` I have set the value for `ViewController` based status bar appearance to `YES`.

[image]

All of the UIViewControllers have the values

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarUIView?.backgroundColor = customColor
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

in viewDidLoad with customColor being a dark shade of blue. I'm also overriding the preferredStatusBarStyle variable to light content.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

All UIViewControllers display the lightContent status bar. I have tried the same in the MoreTabBarController class but it doesn't work. I'm assuming the reason is because it isn't a UIViewController but rather a UITabBarController.

[image]

How do I change the Status bar color to light content in the MoreTabBarController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` 
in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and then 
use `View controller-based status bar appearance` key  and set No for its boolean value in .info plist. 
Its change Status bar color to light content.

Answer (score 0):

Open project settings option you can change status bar's style:

[image]

Next, go back to the Storyboard, Select the `ViewController` and in the Editor menu Select Embedin `NavigationController`. Select the Navigation Bar and in the Attribute Inspector set the Bar Tint color to red.
Build and Run the project, The content of the status bar is dark again, which is the default. The reason for this is, iOS asked for the style of the status bar of the navigation controller instead of the contained `ViewController`.
To change the style of all navigation controller inside the app, change the following method in the `AppDelegate.swift` file.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackOpaque
    return true
    }
```